# xhtml2pdf pip install fail

Tags: python, pip, xhtml2pdf

When I type `pip install xthml2pdf` into the command prompt I'm seeing the following error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xhtml2pdf (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xhtml2pdf
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

After researching this issue I've tried `pip install "xhtml2pdf==0.2.4"` and `pip install html5lib==1.0b8` as well as using conda install but I'm still unable to install the package.

I'm using a Windows machine and I'm fairly new to python so I haven't installed many packages and might be missing some dependencies. I would have assumed these should be installed as part of the `pip install xhtml2pdf` command though.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and know of a fix?

Comment: It seems that your pip couldn't use SSL. try adding Anaconda3 to your path - https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/

Comment: Thanks for your response I couldn't get it to work using the documents but I used "cd C:\.....\anaconda3" followed by the pip install command and I'm still getting the same error message as above

Comment: Yeah, all dependencies are automatically installed by using pip install. This sounds like you're having problems with pip and it doesn't sound like it's a problems with xhtml2pdf. Can you install other packages without problems? Have you tried updating your pip installation?

Comment: It doesn't look like I'm able to install other packages with pip install as it's giving me the same error message. I've changed my directory to the the location of the latest Python installation and typed python -m pip install --upgrade pip but it;s saying my pip installation is up to date (20.2.3)?